# Is it possible to call Java code from a native application?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, native

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to call java function from c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819536/how-to-call-java-function-from-c)
>   [Can C++ call Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987089/can-c-call-java-code)

I have a native application on Linux (i.e. main() is in C++) and I want to reuse some of my Java code.
Can I load JVM libraries and somehow call Java classes?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load the JVM in your native application and invoke stuff using the [Invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp9502)