# Could I use C++ code with JAVA code?

Tags: java, c++, audio

I recently coded alot of java code for a project, and then i had to code something else that I couldn't do in java, but one of my friends could do in C++..
could the codes be united or somewhat?

think of a core game engine made in java and a sound engine made in c++ and i wanna unite them

thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible to use [Java code from C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987089/can-c-call-java-code) and vice versa. Other than that, you'll have to be more specific if you want a specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is a way to call C++ code from inside a Java program.

Refer to this tutorial http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/j-jni.html

It explains how the Java Native Interface, part of the Java Software Development Kit, can be used to call C++ code from Java and Java code from C++ programs.